# Trying to store randomly generated password as a string so then i can save it to a file (Java)

Tags: java

So what I am trying to do is create a random password generator, I have managed to make the system produce a random string of characters based on the char length that the user inputs. What I then want to do is ask the user if they want to save the file. On the file I want to include the name of the website/application and the password.

My problem is I cannot get the random string for the password to be stored as a variable, does anyone know how to fix this?

Code can be seen below:

```
    System.out.println("Please enter the length of password that you require: ");
    int passwordLength = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    Random r = new Random();
    String alphabet = "abcde5678fghijklmn123opqrs?!£$%tuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMN490@#/*(OPQRSTUVWXYZ)";
    for (int i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++) {
        System.out.print(alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length())));

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you mean that you want to collect the password into a String variable instead of printing each character.  Here's how to do that in a completely working example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the length of password that you require: ");
    int passwordLength = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    Random r = new Random();
    String alphabet = "abcde5678fghijklmn123opqrs?!£$%tuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMN490@#/*(OPQRSTUVWXYZ)";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++)
        sb.append(alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length())));
    String password = sb.toString();
    System.out.print(password);
}
```

Result:

```
Please enter the length of password that you require: 
12
j$miDCadnJMd
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use a String Builder, you could do this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the length of password that you require: ");
    int passwordLength = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    Random r = new Random();
    String alphabet = "abcde5678fghijklmn123opqrs?!£$%tuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMN490@#/*(OPQRSTUVWXYZ)";
    String password = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++)
        password += (alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length()))) + "";
    System.out.print(password);
}
```

Comment: For the creation of a small String, this method is ok, but building Strings this way is very inefficient, and should be generally avoided.  Since Strings are immutable, every operation performed directly on a String causes a new String to be created that contains the result of the operation.  The whole String gets copied on each operation.  Using a StringBuilder avoids all of these extra String copies.  It uses a pre-allocated buffer that appended characters are added to with no unnecessary copying.  Just one copy at the end converts the StringBuilder to a String, the desired result.